# How to use ListView to display Firebase Data

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display my Firebase data using a ListView, but I am getting an error.
My code:

```
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inventory, container, false);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uID = currentUser.getUid();

        lv = view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        DatabaseReference refInventory = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("inventory");
        Query queryInventory = refInventory.orderByChild("businessId").equalTo(uID);

        FirebaseListOptions<InventoryModel> items = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<InventoryModel>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.items)
                .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
                .setQuery(queryInventory, InventoryModel.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter(items) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Object model, int position) {
                final TextView pDescriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pDescriptionTextView);
                final TextView pPriceTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pPriceTextView);
                final TextView pNameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pNameTextView);
                final TextView pQuantityTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pQuantityTextView);
                final TextView pTypeTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pTypeTextView);

                InventoryModel item = (InventoryModel) model;

                pNameTextView.setText(item.getProductName());
                pDescriptionTextView.setText(item.getProductDescription());
                pTypeTextView.setText(item.getProductType());
                pPriceTextView.setText(item.getProductPrice());
                pQuantityTextView.setText(item.getProductQuantity());

            }
        };

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.storefrontapp.navdrawer.inventory_fragment$1.populateView(inventory_fragment.java:83)
        at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter.getView(FirebaseListAdapter.java:122)
```

Also, I am using android Fragments.

Comment: One of you TextView objects is null.  You'll have to do some debugging to figure out which one, and why.  It's probably missing from your layout.

Comment: I dont think its the layout. The error line number from the console takes me to ```pNameTextView.setText(item.getProductName());``` Maybe I am not fetching data properly? @DougStevenson

Comment: That wouldn't lead to the `TextView` being `null` in the error you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking up the text views in the wrong parent.

Change

```
final TextView pDescriptionTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.pDescriptionTextView);
```

To

```
final TextView pDescriptionTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.pDescriptionTextView);
```

So starting from `v` instead of `view`, so that it looks it up in the correct row of the recycler. This applies to all views.